# CWNetwork security mode information

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to determine the security type and phyMode of scanned network on 10.7 and above but seems this information has been removed after 10.7 release. So far i was using deprecated API of CWNetwork.securityMode/phyMode but with 10.9 it has been completely removed  so i am not able to determine it. Latest CWNetwork documentation does not have any info about security mode.

Can anyone please help on this.

Edit: Seems like no one has used it....

Thanks,
MP.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the show, but what you probably want to use is:

```
BOOL isOpenNetwork = [myNetwork supportsSecurity:kCWSecurityNone];
```

This is a simple way of checking if the network is secured.
You can see all the security types in CoreWLANTypes.h (or below):

```
enum {
    kCWSecurityNone                 = 0,
    kCWSecurityWEP                  = 1,
    kCWSecurityWPAPersonal          = 2,
    kCWSecurityWPAPersonalMixed     = 3,
    kCWSecurityWPA2Personal         = 4,
    kCWSecurityPersonal             = 5,
    kCWSecurityDynamicWEP           = 6,
    kCWSecurityWPAEnterprise        = 7,
    kCWSecurityWPAEnterpriseMixed   = 8,
    kCWSecurityWPA2Enterprise       = 9,
    kCWSecurityEnterprise           = 10,
    kCWSecurityUnknown              = NSIntegerMax,
};
typedef NSInteger CWSecurity;
```

Comment: Yes I am doing like this only but was thinking to know exact security type as well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with supportsSecurity method doesn't work well for me:

```
main...
{
    CWNetwork *network = [self.scanResults objectAtIndex:row];
    NSLog(@"%@", network);
    NSLog(@"%@", [self securityStringForNetwork:network]);
}

- (NSString*)securityStringForNetwork:(CWNetwork *)network;
{
    NSString *securityString = @"Unknown";

    if ([network supportsSecurity:kCWSecurityNone])
        securityString = @"None";
    else if ([network supportsSecurity:kCWSecurityWEP])
        securityString = @"WEP";
    else if ([network supportsSecurity:kCWSecurityWPAPersonal])
        securityString = @"WPA Personal";
    else if ([network supportsSecurity:kCWSecurityWPAPersonalMixed])
        securityString = @"WPA Personal Mixed";
    else if ([network supportsSecurity:kCWSecurityWPA2Personal])
        securityString = @"WPA2 Personal";
    else if ([network supportsSecurity:kCWSecurityPersonal])
        securityString = @"Personal";
    else if ([network supportsSecurity:kCWSecurityDynamicWEP])
        securityString = @"Dynamic WEP";
    else if ([network supportsSecurity:kCWSecurityWPAEnterprise])
        securityString = @"WPA Enterprise";
    else if ([network supportsSecurity:kCWSecurityWPAEnterpriseMixed])
        securityString = @"WPA Enterprise Mixed";
    else if ([network supportsSecurity:kCWSecurityWPA2Enterprise])
        securityString = @"WPA2 Enterprise";
    else if ([network supportsSecurity:kCWSecurityEnterprise])
        securityString = @"Enterprise";

    return securityString;
}
```

The result is:

[ssid=RiO-Murmansk, bssid=54:04:a6:e9:b3:4e, **security=WPA2 Personal**, rssi=-48, channel= [channelNumber=11(2GHz), channelWidth={20MHz}], ibss=0]

and

**WPA Personal Mixed**

Mismatch.

I would like to know exact security mode. Not the security mode which is able to be supported.

Comment: See @Patrick answer, he is right there's only way to know if security type is  supported to know if it is open network but no way to know exact security type used.

Comment: try switching your if's so option of 'WPA2 Personal' is before the 'WPA Personal mixed' option, I understood it returns "yes" in a few cases so maybe the order should also make sense maybe you put more general option later rater then earlier.